# Display url of git pull

Tags: git, github

I have some `rewrite` rules in my global git config:

```
[url "https://bitbucket.com/"]
    insteadOf = git://bitbucket.com/
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git://github.com/
[push]
    default = simple
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git:// 
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com/
```

I need this for the work firewall. However I still cannot do a git pull:

```
git clone git@github.com:MailOnline/jquery.hammer.js.git
```

But this will work:

```
 git clone https://github.com/MailOnline/jquery.hammer.js.git
```

I would like to be able to display the git clone path to double check it is working as expected.

Comment: Change `insteadOf = git@github.com/` to `insteadOf = git@github.com:` and it should work.